# Access nested array of array of dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to display the value of "description" on table view but I am not able to reach to the "description". Every time I loop it. Example

```
for i in item { 
   let result = i["description"]     
}
```

It returns Type 'Any' has no subscript members

```
[[["description": "Meeting", "comments": "", "projectId": 6, "hours": 0.0, "id": 52, "projectName": "A-DA Internal"], ["description": "Others", "comments": "", "projectId": 6, "hours": 0.0, "id": 53, "projectName": "A-DA Internal"], ["description": "3.1 Project Planning", "comments": "", "projectId": 5, "hours": 0.0, "id": 28, "projectName": "STARWorks ESS"], ["description": "4.1 Analysis & Design", "comments": "", "projectId": 5, "hours": 0.0, "id": 32, "projectName": "STARWorks ESS"], ["description": "4.3 Bug fixes", "comments": "", "projectId": 5, "hours": 0.0, "id": 34, "projectName": "STARWorks ESS"]]]
```

Comment: Tell the compiler that `item` is `[[String:Any]]`

Comment: Don't you have to go 2 levels down to even reach the dictionary? Show the full code you tried please.

Comment: var asd = [Any]()
        for item in arrTask {
            asd.append(item.value)
        }

        print(asd) so far I only able to reach this level after that. It will shows Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: What is arrTask? Please add your full code by editing the question.

Comment: `Any` is *I-have-no-idea*. Use more specific types. The compile **must** know the static types of all subscripted objects.

Answer (score 0):

From the response you have posted above its seems the type is `[[[String : Any]]]`.
So to get to the `[String: Any]` part you will have to dive two level.

```
//let say
let result: [[[String: Any]]] = THE RESPONSE YOU POSTED..

let item = result.flatmap {$0} //this will convert to [[String: Any]]

 //After that your loop will work as expected

 for i in item {
        debugPrint(i["description"])
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your compiler that the **item** through which you want to loop through is of type **[[String:Any]]** only you can get the value for the key **description**.

You can do that the following way:

```
for i in item as! [[String:Any]] { 
   let result = i["description"]     
}
```

Hope this helps. For any queries feel free to leave a comment.